# JSON not well formed error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the below code,

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JSON ex</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" 
            src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
            var accountGrid = [];
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.getJSON('result.json', function(entry){
                    accountGrid.push({
                        name: entry.name,
                        marketValue: entry.marketValue,
                        cash: entry.cash,
                        legend: entry.legend
                    }); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
```

---

result.json

```
{
    'name': 'Account1',
    'marketValue': '10990',
    'cash': '199926',
    'legend': 'orange'
},
{
    'name': 'Account2',
    'marketValue': '156590',
    'cash': '133856',
    'legend': 'darkorange'
}
```

---

I see JSON `not well formed` error. `result.json` sits in the same folder.

Due to this error, `accountGrid` goes empty.

What does it mean to say `not well formed` error, on execution of `jQuery.getJSON`?

Comment: There are online/offline validators that you can use to validate your JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's consider the [grammar of JSON](http://www.json.org/)...

**JSON must be a single value (object, array, etc.)**

A JSON object should be a single value. What you have is two objects separated by a comma. Perhaps you could assign each of these as members of a single object.

```
# a JSON object consists of a single value definition
value
    string
    number
    object
    array
    true
    false
    null

# this value can be an object
object
    {}
    { members }

# or an array
array
    []
    [ elements ]
```

______

**Single-quotation marks are illegal**

JSON forbids the use of single-quotes (`'`) for strings.

```
# a string consists of chars wrapped in double-quotation marks
string
    ""
    " chars "
```

So replace all single quotes to double quotation marks.

The above two things considered, you will end up with something like this:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "name": "Brokerage Account 3",
        "marketValue": "1999990",
        "cash": "1995826",
        "legend": "orange"
    },
    "key2": {
        "name": "Account 3",
        "marketValue": "1949990",
        "cash": "1695856",
        "legend": "darkorange"
    }
}
```

[ [Try it out online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=622e2a2eed3cd355ba288d99804dd0e1) ]

______

**Place objects within an array**

Alternatively, as suggested by @Gerald Schneider, place the objects within an array. The spec says that `value` (defined above) can be an `array`:

```
array
    []
    [ elements ] # elements can multiple values, e.g. objects
```

So your JSON would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Account1",
        "marketValue": "10990",
        "cash": "199926",
        "legend": "orange"
    },
    {
        "name": "Account2",
        "marketValue": "156590",
        "cash": "133856",
        "legend": "darkorange"
    }
]
```

[ [Try it out online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=572498b110113540bd833c1e3de7fed0) ]

______

**Consuming the parsed JSON** (where the JSON is an array)

If you represent your data as an array, your callback should simply assign the resulting parsed JSON to the `accountGrid` variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
    var accountGrid = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('result.json', function(entry){
            accountGrid = entry;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to append the values of entry to `accountGrid`:

```
accountGrid = accountGrid.concat(entry);
```

______

**Writing JSON in the future**

I suggest you edit JSON files within an IDE that supports syntax highlighting for JSON, then these problems would be raised within the editor. Or, [use one of the many online tools available](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/).

Comment: Personally I'd just make it an array by enclosing it in `[]`. Makes it easier to loop over.

Comment: [Try it here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=572498b110113540bd833c1e3de7fed0).